# How to Remove Shellac Primer from Laminate Floor?

Tags: painting, paint, cleaning, stain

I recently used some shellac-based primer to cover some caulk and accidentally sprayed in on laminate flooring not realizing how much of a pain it would be to remove. Does anyone have any suggestions to remove this without damaging the flooring? I have already tried scraping it off with a putty knife, but as you can see, it will not get to the deeper grain? Thanks!

[image: Floor]

[image: Primer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denatured alcohol (ethanol) dissolves the shellac component of shellac based primer. Don't flood the area, try a dab-wipe-dab-wipe action so you don't spread the overspray beyond where it is now.

Don't use vodka or similar. The water in vodka will turn the shellac into a sticky gel that's hard to deal with.

Note that this product when sold in lidded cans uses ethanol as the solvent, but when sold in aerosol cans it also contains acetone. The acetone may have already damaged the surface of your laminate flooring, though ethanol is unlikely to. Even so, check for any change in surface appearance in an inconspicuous place before using denatured alcohol for cleaning.

Comment: And use a nylon bristled brush to scrub the "valleys" on the surface.